# How to make calculations in Notepad++ using regular expressions?

Tags: notepad++

In my text editor, I have the following:

```
abc1
abc2
asdf3
```

I want to replace that with:

```
abc3
abc4
asdf5
```

But in order to do that, I have to make calculations in Notepad++ using regular expressions. How do I do that?

Comment: It's not possible to do calculations with regular expressions in Notepad++

Comment: C# programming questions are off-topic on [su].

Comment: I would ask "what have your tried" but I suspect I already know the answer....can't vote to migrate this question for that reason

Comment: I have removed the C# scope of the question in a dire attempt to salvage the question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's your lucky day because it was just a couple of hours ago that I played a bit with the Python Script plugin of NP++ for the first time.

As the others mentioned, RE is not for maths expressions because they can be too complex (and RE's don't evaluate). However, if it's not a homework tied to RE's, then possible to solve just by trying to eval() each field and write the result on success and the original field when the field is not evaluatable.

```
for line in content.splitlines():
    fields = line.split()
    for i in range( len(fields)):
        try:
            result = eval(fields[i])
            if i > 0:
                newcontent += " "
            newcontent += str(result)
        except:
            if i > 0:
                newcontent += " "
            newcontent += fields[i]
    newcontent += "\n"

editor.clearAll()       
editor.appendText( newcontent)
```

I hope you know how to use the Python Script plugin.